# Getting udev to check audio devices

Tags: bluetooth, bash-scripting, systemd, udev, pipewire

I'm trying to write a udev rule for my bluetooth receiver which, when it connects, runs a script that checks whether a corresponding audio device has also been added, and reconnects if that is not the case. For some reason, when I turn on the receiver and it autoconnects, at first no audio device gets added. I use pipewire-pulse.

Problem is that I don't know how to get udev to check audio devices. `pactl list` doesn't work as root, but that's fine because in theory, `pw-cli list-objects` should work. So my script looks like this:

```
#!/bin/bash

sleep 3

# JR-CB1 connected but not available as audio device
if bluetoothctl devices Connected | grep "25:4E:4A:C7:43:C4" && ! pw-cli list-objects | grep "25_4E_4A_C7_43_C4"; then
    # Reconnect
    bluetoothctl disconnect 25:4E:4A:C7:43:C4
    bluetoothctl connect 25:4E:4A:C7:43:C4
fi
```

With `su` in terminal this works just fine. It reconnects if there is no audio device and does nothing if there is. The output of `pw-cli list-objects | grep "25_4E_4A_C7_43_C4"` after the audio device was added is

```
object.path = "bluez_output.25_4E_4A_C7_43_C4.1:monitor_0"
object.path = "bluez_output.25_4E_4A_C7_43_C4.1:monitor_1"
node.name = "bluez_output.25_4E_4A_C7_43_C4.1"
device.name = "bluez_card.25_4E_4A_C7_43_C4"
object.path = "bluez_output.25_4E_4A_C7_43_C4.1:playback_1"
object.path = "bluez_output.25_4E_4A_C7_43_C4.1:playback_0"
```

and the grep return value is 0 so the if-statement shouldn't run. However, while this works in terminal, in udev it doesn't work for some reason. When logging the script's output when run by udev, the output of `pw-cli list-objects | grep "25_4E_4A_C7_43_C4"` is empty and the return value is 1 which means the reconnect is performed and I get an endless reconnection loop.

Why can't udev list pipewire audio devices? Is there another way?

Comment: Since pulse server (or pipewire equivalent) is in per-user basis. I suppose the most suitable way would be a systemd *user* service. (You can even make it start and stop with e.g. the pipewire-pulse service.) (Also udev isn't really where this sort of persistent loop should be started anyway.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found a solution. As suggested by a comment, I looked into using a service to launch the script. To make systemd aware of the device event, I used this udev rule:

```
/etc/udev/rules.d/60-bluetooth-add-event.rules

CTION=="add", SUBSYSTEM=="bluetooth", TAG+="systemd", ENV{SYSTEMD_WANTS}="bluetooth-add-event.service"
```

(I tried to determine an attribute specific to my bluetooth device, but without the pipewire device, no unique attributes seem to be available to udev, so I'm launching the service whenever any bt device connects and letting the script handle identification.)

The service looks like this:

```
/etc/systemd/system/bluetooth-add-event.service

[Unit]
Description=Runs when bluetooth connection is added
Requires=bluetooth.target
After=bluetooth.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/bin/bluetooth-add-event.sh
Type=exec
Restart=no

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

This not a user service because `pw-cli` can be used by root, just not when run by udev.

(My understanding of systemd unit options is rudimentary, so any suggestions for improvement are welcome.)

The script is the same as before:

```
/usr/bin/bluetooth-add-event.sh

#!/bin/bash

sleep 3

# JR-CB1 connected but not available as audio device
if bluetoothctl devices Connected | grep "25:4E:4A:C7:43:C4" && ! pw-cli list-objects | grep "25_4E_4A_C7_43_C4"; then
    # Reconnect
    bluetoothctl disconnect 25:4E:4A:C7:43:C4
    bluetoothctl connect 25:4E:4A:C7:43:C4
fi
```

Now when I connect the device, the script runs once, doesn't find the audio device, reconnects the bt device, then runs again but does nothing because it finds audio device in `pw-cli list-objects`.